# Component doesn't re-render after state changes

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have an interface with two teams of buttons (features and targets). When I click on a button I want it from one team to go to the other team. I am implementing this with react and redux. My only problem is that when the state is updated and i console log successfully the updated state the component doesn't unless I use forceUpdate(). What I don't understand is that since the state is updated successfully shouldn't the component re-render automatically?

Some.js

```
class Some extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            selectedFeatures:[],
            selectedTargets:[]
        }
    }

    setStateFromProps(){
        this.setState({
            selectedFeatures: this.props.features,
            selectedTargets: this.props.targets,
        }, console.log(this.state.selectedFeatures, this.state.selectedTargets))
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.setStateFromProps()
    }

    render(){

        const { features, targets} = this.props

        const updateLists =(selectedFeature, flag) =>{
            let index
            if  (flag){
                index = features.indexOf(selectedFeature)
                features.splice(index, 1);

                targets.push(selectedFeature)

                this.props.addFeature({features, targets})
            }else{
                index = targets.indexOf(selectedFeature)
                targets.splice(index, 1);

                features.push(selectedFeature)
                this.props.addFeature({targets, features})
            }

            console.log(this.state.selectedFeatures, this.state.selectedTargets)


        }

        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.selectedFeatures.map(feature => {

                    return <div><button key={feature} onClick={() => updateLists(feature, true)}>{feature}</button> <br /></div>
                })}
                <br />
                {this.state.selectedTargets.map(target => {
                    return <div><button key={target} onClick={() =>updateLists(target, false)} >{target}</button> <br /></div>
                })}
            </div>
        );

    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps =(dispatch) =>{
    return {
            addFeature: (data) => dispatch(featureAddedToTargets(data)),
        }
} 
const mapStateToProps= (state)=>{
    return { selectedFeature:state.addFeatureReducer.selectedFeature,
            features: state.addFeatureReducer.features,
            targets: state.addFeatureReducer.targets
    };
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Some);
```

As you can see When I click on a button I trigger the updateLists function that will make the computation to change the send to our only action the new data with the updated feature and target buttons and the action will change the state in the reducer.

featureAddedToTargets Action

```
    export const featureAddedToTargets = (data) =>{
        return {
            type: FEATURE_CHANGED,
            data
        }
    }
```

addFeatureReducer

```
    const initialState = {
        features:['f1','f2','f3','f4','f5'],
        targets:['t1','t2']
    }

    const addFeatureReducer = (state=initialState, action) =>{
        switch(action.type){
            case FEATURE_CHANGED:
                console.log("action: ", action)
                return {...state , state, features: action.data.features, targets: action.data.targets};
            default: 
                return state;
        }
    }
export default combineReducers({ addFeatureReducer })
```

As I said the Some component doesn't re-render and the team of buttons stay the same even though the initialState in reducer has changed and thus the props in Some component have changed as well. I want to understand why is this happening.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tXtM.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured why the component wasn't updating even though the state was updating. It seems that in the updatedLists() I was using push() and splice() directly on the feature and target arrays of the redux store thus mutating my state. Because of the mutation, the component wasn't seeing a change in current and next state. React keeps in memory two versions of the state - The current version and the next. It compares the two and updates the DOM only with the parts that have changed. Due to the fact that I was mutating the state, React was seeing both current and next as the same so it wasn't updating. So I just changed updatedLists(), I applied push() and splice() in random variables (Features and Targets) that later I passed as data to our action, passing their values with the spread operator (As we did before) into the state of the store (initialState).

```
if  (flag){
            index = this.state.selectedFeatures.indexOf(selectedFeature)
            const Features = [...this.state.selectedFeatures]
            Features.splice(index, 1);

            const Targets = [...this.state.selectedTargets]
            Targets.push(selectedFeature)

            console.log('features',features,'targets',targets)
            this.props.addFeature({features: Features , targets: Targets})
        }else{
            index = this.state.selectedTargets.indexOf(selectedFeature)
            const Targets = [...this.state.selectedTargets]
            Targets.splice(index, 1);

            const Features = [...this.state.selectedFeatures]
            Features.push(selectedFeature)

            console.log('features',features,'targets',targets)
            this.props.addFeature({ features:Features, targets: Targets})
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

After you fire an action `FEATURE_CHANGED`, your reducer is returning an updated state, which in turn is propagated via mapStateToProps to your React Component as newProps. In render function, you are mapping over `this.state.selectedFeatures` and `this.state.selectedTargets`. From what I see, it seems, although you are getting newProps `features` and `targets`, you are not updating them in your component's state. You can use `getDerivedStateFromProps` lifecycle to update state as new props arrives.

```
getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if (nextProps.features !== prevState.features && nextProps.targets !== prevState.targets) {
        return ({
           selectedFeatures: nextProps.features,
           selectedTargets: nextProps.targets
        });
    }
    else if (nextProps.features !== prevState.features) {
       return ({
           selectedFeatures: nextProps.features,
        });
    } else if (nextProps.targets !== prevState.targets) {
       return ({
           selectedTargets: nextProps.targets,
        });
    }
}
```

You can refer about it here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops

Comment: This doesn't work and what I would like to know because I have encoutered this problem before is that I follow my component's state in the debugger and also in the console.log and by what it prints, the state seems to update correctly. Still though the component is not re-rendering So the features and targets stay to their original teams. If I do a forceUpdate() at the end of updateLists() then and only then the component renders with the update state. But I don't want to update manually the component since it should be re-rendering automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
setStateFromProps(){
        this.setState({
            selectedFeatures: this.props.features,
            selectedTargets: this.props.targets,
        }, console.log(this.state.selectedFeatures, this.state.selectedTargets))
    }
```

try changing this to

```
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if(this.props.features !== prevProps.features || this.props.targets !== prevProps.targets) {
      this.setState({
            selectedFeatures: this.props.features,
            selectedTargets: this.props.targets,
        }, console.log(this.state.selectedFeatures, this.state.selectedTargets))
    }

}
```